# State update gets delayed when using useState<T> inside a select list

Tags: reactjs

I declared a `useState<ICurrency>` as

```
const [hwSalesPriceCurrency, setHwSalesPriceCurrency] = useState<ICurrency>();
```

There's an html with  inside of which I have a select list as

```
<label>
        Price Currency12:<span className="redStar">*</span>
</label>
<Select
        type="input-single"
        placeholder="Select Currency"
        disabled={false}            
        label={
          uscCurrencyEdit !== ""
            ? uscCurrencyEdit
            : hwSalesPriceCurrency
              ? hwSalesPriceCurrency.unit
              : ""
        }            
        items={currencies.map(v => ({ title: v.unit, value: v }))}            
        onChange={({ value }: { value: ICurrency }) => {              
          console.log("onChange value::");
          console.log(value);              
          setHwSalesPriceCurrency(value);
          uscCurrencyChanged(value.unit);              
          pricingTotal();
        }}
/>
```

When I select a different value, onChange gets fired. I see the value in onChange to the latest values that I selected but `setHwSalesPriceCurrency(value)` doesn't update the state to the latest value. It updates it to the previous value. There's an another text box beside to it and it has no relation to this select list but then after inputing some number into the text box, the value gets updated.

Is there any way I can make the state update instantly without inputing some number into an another text box?

Comment: What do uscCurrencyChanged(value.unit) and pricingTotal() do? Are there any other places in this component that you update state? It would help if you edited your post to include a [minimal reproducible example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: There's no other place in code that sets the state of ```HwSalesPriceCurrency```.  Pricing total utilizes the value of ```HWSalesPriceCurrency```

Comment: It would help if you edited your post to include a minimal reproducible example or a code sandbox or something similar.

Comment: There are lot of things atop of this one. I should see how I can create a minimal reproducible example